# How to convert Hexadecimal to JSON object

Tags: node.js, json, api, hex

API documentation github link is  https://github.com/thundercomb/poetrydb#api-reference
My goal is to fetch data from the api and convert the received data to JSON.I have used https.get to fetch data from the api and I got a hexadecimal value so I converted it into string using .toString() and now when I am trying to parse it with JSON.parse() it is showing "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

```js
const express = require('express');
const { get } = require('express/lib/response');
const https = require('https');

const app = express();
let authorName;

const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

readline.question(`What's your name?`, name => {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
  authorName = name;
  readline.close();
  getfunction()
})

function getfunction(){
  const url = "https://poetrydb.org/author/"+ authorName +"/all.json";
  https.get(url,function(res){
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      if(res.statusCode==200){
          res.on("data",function(data){
              // console.log(data);
              var hex = data.toString();
              // console.log(hex);
              var parsed = JSON.parse(hex);
              console.log(parsed);
          });
      }
  });
}
```

[This is my output have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqoVq.png)

The ultimate goal is to get api data(hexadecimal) and convert it into JSON(JSON object)

[When I comment the JSON.parse() line and print the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idt91.png) .

[When I stringify() the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrDyo.png) .